# how to add newsletter link page to toplink

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, toplinks

I want to add newsletter link to my top link block like first link.
I think that it can works adding some string in layout.xml files.
I've tried to add this code into customer.xml
but the newsletter link doesn't appear.

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Newsletter</label><url helper="newsletter"/><title>Newsletter</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Anyone can help me to understand how works the toplinks adding?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way which could be possible is to apply a custom template to `top.links`

Add this to `local.xml`

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/template/newToplinks.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
<default>
```

You can now add your items to `newToplinks.phtml`

the above would help to maybe insert the whole newsletter `block`, or whatever you would require in to top.link area using a new template file.

**OR**

to add a `new link`;

Open `app/design/frontend/default/TEMPLATE/layout/customer.xml`

Add the following at the bottom before closing `</layout>` tag.

```
<default>
<reference name="top.links">
  <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
    <label>Newsletter</label>
    <url>newsletter</url>
    <title>Sign up to our newsletter</title>
    <prepare>true</prepare>
    <position>2</position>
  </action>
</reference>
</default>
```

This will create a `link` to `www.URL.com/newseltter/`

Hope this help.

Comment: I use to add my custom link successfully, now how could i also show number of items like wishlist and cart shows?